# PowerMock - Singleton Instance test

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

```
public Data extraMethod(Data data) // interface Data
{
    Data d = Singleton.getInstance().sort(data.get() , "desc");
    //do something, logical
    return d;
}
```

How can I mock the object Data(the singleton extra return result), class `Singleton` has a static method `getInstance` and no public constructor. I want to test the logical part, test `extraMethod` without Data sort operation.

Comment: Have you tried to mock `Singleton.getInstance()` so that it returns an object of your choice?

Answer (score 0):

You could get away without PowerMock if you would spy your class under test and create a package level method that would be return the `Singleton`.
You still need to set-up what should happen when the `sort` method is invoked:

**1)** Class under test

```
public Data extraMethod(Data data) // interface Data
{
    Data d = getSingleton().sort(data.get() , "desc");
    //do something, logical
    return d;
}

Singleton getSingleton(){
   return Singleton.getInstance();
}
```

**2)** Test

```
@Spy
private MyClass myClassSpy = new MyClass();

@Mock
Singleton singletonStub;

@Mock
Data dataStub;

@Before
public void init(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception{
  // Arrange
  doReturn(singletonStub).when(myClassSpy).getSingleton();
  when(dataStub.get()).thenReturn(...);
  when(singletonStub.sort(any(Data.class), "desc")).thenReturn(/* some data*/);

  // Act and Assert        
}
```